# Can't add migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Models:  `GropsAndProducts`, `Groups`, `Products`:

```
    public class GropsAndProducts
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Products")]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Groups")]
        public int GroupId { get; set; }

        public Groups Groups { get; set; }
        public Products Products { get; set; }
    }

    public class Groups
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Discription { get; set; }
        public List<GropsAndProducts> groupAndProducts { get; set; }
    }
    public class Products
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Count { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Price { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Discount { get; set; }
        public string Discription { get; set; }
        public List<GropsAndProducts> groupAndProducts { get; set; }
    }
```

Context:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySite.Models;
using System.Data;

namespace MySite.Data
{
    public class DbProductsAndGroupsContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbProductsAndGroupsContext(DbContextOptions<DbProductsAndGroupsContext> option) 
            : base (option)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Products> products;
        public DbSet<Groups> groups;
        public DbSet<GropsAndProducts> gropsAndProducts;
    }
}
```

Startup configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DbProductsAndGroupsContext>(option => 
            option.UseMySql(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), x=> x.MigrationsHistoryTable("__MyMigrationsHistory", "mySchema"))
                );
            services.AddDbContext<DbUserContex>(options =>
                options.UseMySql(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<Users>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbUserContex>();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Now the problem is:

The first migration (From `UserIdentity`) was performed normally (that is, a new database was created as well as tables with records). But after I created the second context and try to execute the command (in the package manager) ʻEntityFrameworkCore \ Add-Migration -name: asdf -context: DbProductsAndGroupsContext`, then ** blank ** migration is added. Why can it be like that ??? I will be glad to any information.

Comment: what was your second migration supposed to be adding. it's hard to tell why things don't show up if we don't know what is supposed to show up. might be helpful if you post your models at the time the first migration was created and then post was you added that shouldve been included in the second migration

Comment: @GregH The first migration involved the `Users: UserIdentity` model and its context. After the update-daatabase was executed, 8 tables were added to the database. It is conceived that the migration should add 3 tables to the database, but the migration is generated empty.

Comment: If you're doing a many-to-many relationship between Group and Products, you'll need to map the relationships to the junction table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took me a bit to spot your issue. Your `DbSet`s need to have getters and setters for EntityFramework to be able to locate the models so that it can generate the needed migration.

You should change:

```
public DbSet<Products> products;
public DbSet<Groups> groups;
public DbSet<GropsAndProducts> gropsAndProducts;
```

To:

```
public DbSet<Products> products { get; set; }
public DbSet<Groups> groups { get; set; }
public DbSet<GropsAndProducts> gropsAndProducts { get; set; }
```

Note that by convention, `DbSet` property names are normally upper cased (i.e: `Products` instead of `products`). Another thing to point out is you can simplify your `GropsAndProducts` (please fix the spelling!) model by changing it to:

```
public class GropsAndProducts
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    public Groups Group { get; set; }
    public Products Product { get; set; }
}
```

The foreign key annotation isn't necessary if you follow EF naming conventions (The `Group` navigation property's foreign key is `GroupId`). The property name `Groups` probably doesn't make as much sense anyway since the property is only holding a single `Group`